# Next/Prev buttons for nodes based on nodereference field

Tags: 7, nodes, database, paging

By using this tutorial http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2011/09/12/adding-pager-navigation-nodes-drupal-7 I have created next/prev buttons for my images.

But as I have a lot of galleries and I need to filter images not only by node type but also by node reference field value.

The machine name of my field is `field_pers_gallery` and in phpmyadmin it is assigned to a particular gallery by `field_pers_gallery_nid`.

I'm note good at creating db query, could anybody help with any advices?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you managed to get your pager working yet, but I've just modified a piece of code to create a pager based on node reference. You're free to use it as you see fit. You can go to my blog to see it:

http://www.visionarymedia.nl/blog/drupal-pager-based-node-reference

Comment: eventually I used Free Pager module for this. Anyway thank you for your reply I will learn your tutorial